# How to retrieve Combobox state

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, combobox

I'm building tkinter app and I use some `ttk` widgets, including `Combobox`. I need to obtain status of `combobox` in order to perform some action. However, when I try to get state, it gives me something strange.

This is output from `print(self.combobox["state"], DISABLED)` command:

```
(<index object at 0x1f72c30>, 'disabled')
```

where `DISABLED` is variable from `Tkinter`.

I also tried to get state using `self.combobox.state()`, but the output is the same.

Note: I can change state of `combobox` using `self.combobox["state"] = NORMAL` and `self.combobox["state"] = DISABLED` (I can see that `combobox` is white/gray when I change state).

Comment: `self.combobox['state'].string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dir()` to see what methods and properties  has object.

```
print( dir(self.combobox['state']) )
```

result

```
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', 
 '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', 
 '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', 
 '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', 'string', 'typename']
```

You can see `string` (method or property)

If you check

```
 print( self.combobox['state'].string == tk.NORMAL )
```

you get `True`

`str()` works too

```
 print( str(self.combobox['state']) == tk.NORMAL )
```

---

**EDIT:** minimal working example for test:

```
try:
    # Python 2
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk
except:
    # Python 3
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()

c = ttk.Combobox(root)
c.pack()

print(c['state'], c['state'] == tk.NORMAL)

print('normal:',   c['state'].string == tk.NORMAL, str(c['state']) == tk.NORMAL)
print('disabled:', c['state'].string == tk.DISABLED, str(c['state']) == tk.DISABLED)

c['state'] = tk.DISABLED

print('normal:',   c['state'].string == tk.NORMAL, str(c['state']) == tk.NORMAL)
print('disabled:', c['state'].string == tk.DISABLED, str(c['state']) == tk.DISABLED)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also found that `self.combobox.instate([DISABLED, ])` will return `True` or `False`. Note that argument here must be a list of states.